# How do I set font for Roman section number in koma scrartcl?

Tags: fonts, koma-script

I am trying to set section font to small caps using `setkomafont` and `thesection` to Roman. Though this sets the font correctly the section number is not scaled correctly. See the attached screen shot. How can I scale the section number to section text?[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% this works
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\large\scshape}

% tried this but doesnt work
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\large\scshape\Roman{section}}




\usepackage[protrusion=allmath,tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{i. the mighty introduction}
\lipsum
\section{ii method}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font size is already the same without adding `\large` and `\scshape` to the definition of `\thesection`. The difference it the difference of upper case letters in small caps and lower case letters in small caps. So it seems, you want `\roman{section}` instead of `\Roman{section}`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% this works
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\large\scshape}

% tried this but doesnt work
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\roman{section}}

\usepackage[protrusion=allmath,tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{i. the mighty introduction}
\lipsum
\section{ii method}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: If you want you can force the section title text to lower case automatically:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% this works
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\large\scshape}

% tried this but doesnt work
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\roman{section}}% using \roman instead of \Roman still needed!
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #2\MakeLowercase{#3}}\MakeLowercase{#4}%
  }{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}#4%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[protrusion=allmath,tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{The Mighty Introduction}% will be automatically changed to lower case in section title (but not in running head or ToC)
\lipsum
\section{Method}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]